# Matplotlib - usage of Scatter plot with specific color assigment

Tags: matplotlib, colors, scatter-plot

Just my first post, it should a very easy one.
I have to do an exercise in which i have a dataframe with several variables and i have to produce a scatter graph where i plot in the y axis the "Price", in the x axis the "Weight" and where i apply a specific color pattern to the dots based on the "Priority" (which goes from 1 to 10).

The defined colors to be applied are:

```
`colors=["navy","lawngreen","red","green","purple","steelblue","orange","darkred","yellow","chocolate"]
```

`

So "Priority=1" should be colors="navy", "Priority=2" should be colors="lawngreen",etc

Therefore i tried to do the following:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("example.csv")
plt.scatter(df.Price,df.Weight,c=df.Priority,s=90)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel('Price')
plt.ylabel('Weight');
```

``

But the coloring that i get obviously does not match the colors predefined (they is just a ramdon color assigned to each of the values of "Priority" variable.
How do i link the defined colors with the Priority variable values?
I tried to build a dictionary to use it in the c argument of the plt.scatter line but i couldnt get any proper result so maybe i'm formulating it wrongly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first, there is a miss match between your graph definition and what you actually do:

> a scatter graph where i plot in the y axis the "Price", in the x axis the "Weight"

but you plot "Price" along the x axis and "Weight" along the y axis :

```py
# [...]
plt.scatter(df.Price, df.Weight, c=df.Priority, s=90)
plt.xlabel('Price')
plt.ylabel('Weight')
```

Getting back to your main question, you're on the good track. Simply define a custom colormap from the list of colors with `ListedColormap` ([see doc here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap.html)) and it should be good.

Here is an example with fake data for price, weight and priority (only 3 priority values here)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np

# Fake data
price = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100))
weight = price + np.random.randint(-20, 20, size=(100))
priority = np.random.randint(0, 3, size=(100))

# Create the custom colormap
colors = ["navy", "lawngreen", "red"]
cmap = ListedColormap(colors)

# Scatter with priority as color and the correct colormap
plt.scatter(weight, price, c=priority, cmap=cmap, s=90)
```

[image]

Comment: You also need to add `vmin` and `vmax` to have the coloring consistent, also when some of the highest or lowest priorities wouldn't be present.  You can do`plt.scatter(..., vmin=0.5, vmax=10.5)` to get a nice accompanying colorbar via `plt.colorbar()`.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick and precise support, you are good!

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Loop over the possible values of `priority`, change the color, associate a label with each priority/color couple, and finally produce a legend.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(2023_03_29)

Npt, Npr = 150, 10
wgt = 30 + 20*np.random.random(Npt)
pri = np.random.randint(1, Npr+1, Npt)
prc = wgt*(190+np.random.randint(0, 21, Npt)+3*pri)
color = ("C%d"%n for n in range(1,11))
for p in range(min(pri), max(pri)+1):
    i = pri==p
    plt.scatter(wgt[i], prc[i], color=next(color), label="%d"%p, zorder=5)
plt.legend(title='Priority')
plt.grid(axis='both')
plt.show()
```